is it possible to change Response JSON schema Format to OpenAI Assistant during session?
I'm trying to start OpenAI Assistant with Python, and don't understand how to use it correctly:
Basically, I want to ask several questions in a single run (I hope that some data remains in the context window), but with a different output format.
To do that I call
assistant.response_format = {"type": "json_schema",  "json_schema" : outputFormat}

where outputFormat is a dict of the required structure
{
  "name": "mySchema",
  "strict": false,
  "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": []
  }
}

but I found that the answer is always formatted with the JSON schema I uploaded in the playground for the test. what can I do to get data in desired format?

I hope that somebody will solve this exact problem. But, alternatively, you can create multiple assistants with different structured outputs and link to the same thread. This should also work.

Practically, I was using 'completion' for structuring the output. just surprising, that i cannot tune it for assistance during the process

This should work without creating new assistant. Just use .update function and map to current assistant.id:
client.beta.assistants.update(
    assistant_id=assistant.id,
    response_format={"type": "json_schema",  "json_schema" : outputFormat}
    )

